# c++: Search in a map without using an iterator

Tags: c++, stdmap

Consider I have this:

```
std::map<int, int> intMap;
intMap[11] = 21; 
intMap[12] = 22; 
intMap[13] = 23; 
intMap[14] = 24; 

int val = 0;
```

When I want to find the value of map[11], if exists, and put it into `val` I'm using:

```
std::map<int, int>::iterator it = intMap.find(11);
if(it != intMap.end())  
    val = it->second;
```

Is there a way of doing this without using an iterator? I mean, a shorter way.

`int val = intMap[11]` isn't an option for me since it adds 11 as a key to intMap if it wasn't there yet, something I'm not interested in. see [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/operator%5b%5d/).

Comment: I omitted the check I'm doing, edited.

Comment: The question makes relatively little sense. If you *know* the element exists, you can use `m[x]` or `*m.find(x)`. Otherwise, i.e. if you *don't* know, then you have to have a mechanism to tell whether the element existed.

Comment: @KerrekSB, see Golgauth's answer.

Comment: @SteveJessop where is the UB? I can't spot it. `operator[]` will initialize a value on the fly, and he is testing the iterator against `intMap.end()` before dereferencing it.

Comment: @Arne: the code in the question was edited in response to my comment. Originally there was no check against `intMap.end()` (and since there's still no `else` clause, we still don't really know how the questioner's code handles that case).

Comment: @SteveJessop ah ok - quick editing too quick to show up in history ;-)

Comment: @ArneMertz, sorry for that :)

Comment: @Subway: I'm not a fan. It's inefficient and makes gratuitous assumptions for no reason.

Comment: @KerrekSB, that's correct. But why should it be obvious that no other way exist out there.

Comment: What is your motivation here?  Less code?  Better efficiency?  Laziness?

Comment: @JohnDibling, clearness.

Comment: What could be more clear than idiomatic code?

Comment: @JohnDibling, `at(Key)` looks clearer to me. Too bad I'm not using c++11 (yet).

Comment: @John: idiomatic code that doesn't require a temporary variable would be clearer than idiomatic code that does :-) This is usually verbose in any language, though: use a value in a test and then use the value again in one of the following cases. And as soon as you *don't* use the iterator value twice, you find yourself doing the lookup twice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In *c++11* `map` has a new method called `at(Key)` which will return a reference to the mapped value or throw an exception if the `Key` is not present at the map.

In *c++* you will need to have an intermediary iterator.

Comment: "c++11" is still "c++". Also, you don't _have_ to have an intermediary iterator. You could do something like this: `(map.count(x) ? map[x] : default_value)`

Comment: @karadoc You are performing the search twice. That's why I prefer iterators.

Comment: @AndréPuel: If the insertion is optionally desired, one could even use `lower_bound` conditionally followed by hinted insertion. All in all, iterators do a fine job here.

Comment: @AndréPuel I think iterators are fine for the job; and it's better not to search twice. I only objecting to the use of the word 'need'. (nitpicking)

Answer (score 3):

André already mentions the new `at()` function. In other circumstances, the following might be useful:

```
template <typename Map, typename K, typename T>
T get(Map &map, const K &key, T def) {
    typename Map::const_iterator it = map.find(key);
    return (it == map.end() ? def : it->second);
}
```

Use it like:

```
int val = get(intMap, 11, 0);
```

You can also have a `const` version, with the advantage of returning a reference (the non-const version returns a value, because returning a reference to a default is rather limiting):

```
template <typename Map, typename K, typename T>
const T& get(const Map &map, const K &key, const T &def) {
    typename Map::const_iterator it = map.find(key);
    return (it == map.end() ? def : it->second);
}
```

Just for fun, this code is concise but it might lose for clarity. It does what you say in a comment below: nothing in the case where `11` is not in the map:

```
BOOST_FOREACH(const std::pair<int,int> &newval, intMap.equal_range(11)) {
    val = newval.second;
}
```

Comment: What I want where the key doesn't exist is to have val staying with its original value, as if I did nothing.

Comment: @Subway: in which case you can do `val = get(intMap, 11, val);` (as long as `val` isn't volatile). In fact for that case there's no problem with the non-const version taking a non-const reference for the default value, and returning a reference, so if your real value type is (unlike `int`) non-trivial to copy then you can avoid any expensive copies provided that the type special-cases self-assignment.

Answer (score 2):

This could work too, I guess :

```
int val;
if (intMap.count(11)) val = intMap[11];
```

Simple check of the key presence...

So in a single line with default_value, as suggested by Karadoc :

```
int val = (intMap.count(x) ? intMap[x] : default_value);
```

Comment: Note that this involves two lookups if the value exists. Not a problem per se, but it's nice to remember it if performance matters.

Comment: One thing that bothers me in this approach is that you are copying the value, while in some cases it is better to access a reference to the value. So, using exceptions, we could do something like `if( intMap.count(11) == 0 ) throw ...; int& val = intMap[11];`

Comment: Right, but dealing with exception can be a matter too, moreover the OP asked for short code...

Answer (score 0):

Generally, yo'll have to check for the existance of the key some way. You could however write some function that does the checking and gives the value, so when you call it you'll have a one-liner. You'll need some default value for when the key does not exist in the map. Here's a quick impl for that:

```
template <class Map, class U>
auto getOrDefault(Map const& m, typename Map::key_type const& key, U&& default_val) 
  -> typename Map::mapped_type
{
  auto pos = m.find(key);
  return pos != m.end() ? pos->second : std::forward<U>(default_val);
}

template <class Map>
auto getOrDefault(Map const& m, typename Map::key_type const& key) 
  -> typename Map::mapped_type
{
  typedef typename Map::mapped_type Value;
  return getOrDefault(m, key, Value{});   
}

//call:
int val = getOrDefault(intMap, 11);       // 0 if key 11 does not exist
int val2 = getOrDefault(intMap, 42, -1);  //-1 if key 42 does not exist
```

*Note:* I didn't manage to give `default_val` a default argument - maybe someone can help me out with that. gcc 4.7.2 could not deduce `U` when I tried with `U&& default_val = typename Map::mapped_type{}`